# Returning the inner namespace of a class as dictionary

Tags: python, variables, namespaces

Imagine we have a class like as below:

```
class P1(object):
    def __init__(self,value=0,src='admin'):
        self.value=value
        self.src=src
```

Is it possible to add a method that returns the name inner variables as a dictionary with name as the name and the value as the value like this:

```
def getDict(self):
    return dictionary(variables)
```

which returns:

```
{
  'value':0,
  'src':'admin'
}
```

PS I know it can be down by hard coding it, I am asking if there is Pythonic way of doing it with one method call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__):

> A dictionary or other mapping object used to store an object’s (writable) attributes.

```
def getDict(self):
    return self.__dict__
```

or [`vars()` builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars), which simply returns the `__dict__` attribute:

```
return vars(self)
```

Warning: Note that this returns a reference to the actual namespace, and any changes you make to the dictionary will be reflected to the instance.

Comment: to be safer, I would probably copy that dict, because the one you are returning *is* the namespace of the object, and it might not be clear that this method is doing that

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Fair enough, added a warning, but the title of the question is literally "inner namespace of a class as dictionary".

Comment: yes @Selcuk I am actually looking for the namespace itself.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `vars` example:

```
return vars(self)
```

Output:

```
{'value': 0, 'src': 'admin'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use magic methods. If not create your own method which returns the dict of value and src. Your code:

```
class P1(object):
    def __init__(self,value=0,src='admin'):
        self.value=value
        self.src=src
    def getdict(self):
        return {"value":self.value,"src":self.src}      #manual return of dict


x=P1(5,"user")      #checking for non default values
print(x.getdict())

x=P1()              #checking for default values
print(x.getdict())
```